# Почему цикл проходит один раз?

Tags: java, android-studio, циклы

У меня есть два цикла: один внешний, другой внутренний. Внутренний цикл проходит столько сколько я ему задал. А внешний проходит только один раз, но 
я не понимаю почему. Объясните пожалуйста.

```
   try
    {
        Document documents = Jsoup.connect("http://vuzopedia.ru/vuzfilter?vuz=&price%5B%5D=0&price%5B%5D=1000000"
                + "&mat="
                + Maths + "&rus="
                + Russian + "&fiz=" + Physics + "&obshe="
                + Studies + "&ist=" + History + "&biol=" + Biology + "&inform="
                + Informatics + "&him=" + Chemistry + "&liter=" + Literature + "&georg=" + Geography
                + "&inyaz=" + English
        ).get();
        pagination = documents.select(".pagination li");
        countOfUniversity = documents.select(".vcount");
        String[] vcount = countOfUniversity.text().split("\\s");



        for(int i = 0; i < Integer.valueOf(pagination.last().text()); i++)
        {
            Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://vuzopedia.ru/vuzfilter?vuz=&price%5B%5D=0&price%5B%5D=1000000"
                    + "&mat="
                    + Maths + "&rus="
                    + Russian + "&fiz=" + Physics + "&obshe="
                    + Studies + "&ist=" + History + "&biol=" + Biology + "&inform="
                    + Informatics + "&him=" + Chemistry + "&liter=" + Literature + "&georg=" + Geography
                    + "&inyaz=" + English + "&page=" + String.valueOf(i)
            ).get();
            vuz = document.select(".itemVuzTitle");
            countOfUniversityOfPages = document.select(".vuzesfullnorm");

            for (int t = 0; t < Integer.valueOf(vcount[1]) - 11; t++)
            {
                NameOfUniversities = vuz.get(t).text();
                Log.e("GLEEE", NameOfUniversities);
                doc = Jsoup.connect(urlF + NameOfUniversities).get();
                webSites = doc.select(".r a[href]");
                UrlOfUniversities = webSites.attr("href");
                items.add(new Items(NameOfUniversities, UrlOfUniversities));
                if(t % countOfUniversityOfPages.size() == 0)
                {
                    t = 0;
                }
            }
        }




    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Integer.valueOf(pagination.last().text());  - проверили значение ?

Comment: Да, оно Integer.valueOf(pagination.last().text()); 42

Comment: @8_leeeroooy_8, а это проверили? Integer.valueOf(vcount[1])

Comment: Да, Integer.valueOf(vcount[1])  это 299

Comment: Уверены, что итерация происходит только 1 раз? Попробуйте счетчик поставить, во время итерации выводить в логи

Comment: Да, итерация происходит 1 раз

Comment: Хмм, исключений никаких не падает ?

Comment: Нет, исключений нет